# Hibernate bug, how to workaround?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, ora-00907

I use Hibernate 3.5.3, and Oracle 10g database

I have bean with following relation

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name="dispenser_accounts",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="terminal_id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="dispenser_section_id"))
@MapKey(name="dispenserNumber")
private Map<Integer, DispenserAccount> activeDispensers = new HashMap<Integer, DispenserAccount>();
```

When I trying to fetch data from activeDispensers hibernate generate sql with wrong syntax

```
SQL Error: 907, SQLState: 42000
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

How to workaround this bug?

Thanks!

Comment: Well for one, find what SQL is being issued.

Comment: I already fount it, but i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use the `MapKeyColumn` annotation here? Can you show the physical model? By the way, is there any Jira issue open for this "bug"?

Comment: Could you please post the generated query instead if the oracle error?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is probably to overwrite a particular method in the Oracle dialect and fix the problem (hard to say without seeing the SQL).

You could try switching to a different Oracle dialect that may not have the same bug. e.g. Oracle9Dialect.